# XSL: How do I assign the value of an XML element to a variable (minimal change to page below)?

Tags: xslt, variables, element, param

See [xslt to operate on element value before displaying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468522/xslt-to-operate-on-element-value-before-displaying) for the original XML and XSL. I got an answer to my question there.

My other question on [this same XML/XSL](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog) is: if I would like to capture the value of an element (such as the "title" element) in an XSL local variable, and then operate on it, how do I capture that value and assign it to a variable? I have the feeling it has something to do with XSL "param", but I am not sure.

So, on [that same code](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog), what is the *minimal* change to the XSL so that I'll have the value of title in a variable?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You use the xsl:variable statement to create a variable. Either of the following will work

```
<xsl:variable name="cdtitle"><xsl:value-of select="title"/></xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="cdtitle" select="title"/>
```

They statement in this case would have to be within the  loop.

To use the variable, you can then just do this, assuming the variable is in scope.

```
<xsl:value-of select="$cdtitle"/>
```

Please note, despite the name, xsl:variables are not variable. Once set, they cannot be changed. You would have to create a new variable with a new name if you wanted to modify the value.

Comment: Thanks. Just so I learn all common syntaxes, isn't there also a syntax where I declare the variable first, and then set its value? With your comment on that, I will likely mark this as the accepted answer.

In any case, I searched your note "xsl:variables are not variable" and realize I'll have to read, for example, "http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/xsltc/xsl_variable_design.html" carefully to understand all about xsl variables and parameters.

Comment: www.w3schools.com is another good place to go to learn about XSLT. See http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_w3celementref.asp for a list of XSLT elements, for example.

Comment: Now I've tried both options and they work. Thanks for answer and additional xsl reference. I think I'm on my way now!

Comment: Thank you much for a solid XSL usage example!